# Can i wrap the React Context API inside getInitialProps/getServerSideProps/getStaticProps

Tags: reactjs, next.js

How can i call an action creator with React Context API inside getInitialProps/getServerSideProps/getStaticProps of NextJs?

Using the redux with NextJs, i can access the `store` and then dispatch an action creator. But, with React Context API i don't know how to do this.

Redux example:

```
Search.getInitialProps = async ({ store }) => {
   store.dispatch(fetch('next-js'));
});
```

How can i do this with the React Context API?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Within the Context provider, you can do something like this

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
        // Call an external API endpoint to get posts.
        // You can use any data fetching library
        const res = await fetch("https://www.mocky.io/")
        const search = await res.json()

        // By returning { props: search }, the Search component
        // will receive `search` as a prop at build time
        return {
            props: {
                search,
            },
        }
    }
```